# What's the meaning of printing a thread instance in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

For example,

```
System.out.println( Thread.currentThread() );
```

gives

```
Thread[main,5,main]
```

What does [main,5,main] refer to? I am guessing perhaps one of them is the name, but I want to know what it all means precisely.

Answer (score 10):

From the javadoc of [Thread](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#toString%28%29):

```
public String toString()
```

Returns a string representation of this thread, including the thread's name, priority, and thread group.

Answer (score 7):

In the result:

Thread[main,5,main]

- main is the thread's name
- 5 is the priority and
- main is the thread group.

The function [`currentThread()`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#currentThread%28%29) returns a reference to the currently executing thread object and when we try to print any object, the [`toString()`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#toString()) method of the corresponding class gets called, so in this case toString() method of the Thread class gets called and it returns a string representation of this thread, including the thread's name, priority, and thread group.