# What is the meaning of output which gets printed when i try to print a thread object in java

Tags: java, multithreading, object

Instead of using `getName()` to print the name of thread, i tried to see what gets printed when i print the object of a `Thread` class.I thought it should print something in the form of `Thread@hashcodeOfObject` but it prints out `Thread[main,5,main]`.

This is the code -

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Thread t=Thread.currentThread();    
        System.out.println(t);
    }
```

I dont understand why it prints `5` in it and `main` two times.Can someone explain why it prints out in this format ?

Comment: Look at the `toString()` method of `Thread`.

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963324/whats-the-meaning-of-printing-a-thread-instance-in-java